# how to avoid error A control with ID 'SqlDataSource1' could not be found

Tags: mysql, asp.net, gridview

In this prgram i am getting below error:

> The `DataSourceID` of **GridView1** must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID `SqlDataSource1` could not be found.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost;database=dbconnect;user id=root;password=search;")

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_display_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_display.Click
        Dim connection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost;database=dbconnect;user id=root;password=search;")
        Dim mydataset As New DataSet()
        Dim mydataadpter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()


        Dim mysql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select * from userinfo", connection)
        connection.Open()


        mydataadpter.SelectCommand = mysql
        mydataadpter.Fill(mydataset, "product")
        Try
            'GridView1.DataSource = mydataset
            GridView1.DataBind()

            GridView1.DataMember = "product"

            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: can I have code for the your .aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the DataSourceID attribute and its value (`DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`) from your GridView1 control inside the source view (.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the DataSourceID property is designed to be used in an ASPX page and you are in the code. You want to use the DataSource property instead. It is looking in your ASPX page for a control named "SqlDataSource1" and there is not one. If you create this SqlDataSource1 object in the ASPX page instead of in the code you will be able to set the DataSourceID to the ID of the SqlDataSource1 object

```
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
```

Comment: yes choose data source.. i selected sqlDataSource1... now i selected none... and it display the record

Comment: have you know from where i get good knowledge about asp.net 2010 and mysql db connectivity